# Mapping exception thrown by NHibernate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, hibernate, nhibernate

I have the following models:

**WeatherForecast:**

```
namespace TravelAssistant.Model.HelperModels.Weather
public class WeatherForecast:EntityBase<int>
{
    public IList<DayForecast> ForecastDays { get; set; }

    public LocationBase ForecastLocation  { get; set; }

    public void Init(Location.LocationBase location)
    {
        this.ForecastLocation = location;
    }

    protected override void Validate()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    } 
}
```

**LocationBase:**

```
 namespace TravelAssistant.Model.HelperModels.Location
    public class LocationBase:EntityBase<int>
    {  

        public string WorldRegion { get; set; }

        public string City { get; set; }

        public string Country { get; set; }

        public string Zipcode { get; set; }

        public string StreetNameNumber { get; set; }
   }
```

where EntityBase defines an id of type T, and the following .hbm files

**WeatherForecast.hbm.xml:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
        namespace="TravelAssistant.Model.HelperModels.Weather"
                assembly="TravelAssistant.Model">

    <class name="WeatherForecast" table="WeatherForecasts" lazy="false" >
        <id  name="Id" column="WeatherForecastID"  
                           type="int" unsaved-value="0">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>

        <many-to-one name="ForecastLocation"
                   cascade="all" 
                   class="LocationBase" 
                   column="LocationID" 
                   not-null="false" />

        <bag name="ForecastDays" lazy="false" >
            <key column="WeatherForecastID"/>
            <one-to-many class="DayForecast"></one-to-many>
        </bag>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

LocationBase.hbm.xml

```
    <id  name="Id" column="LocationID" type="int" unsaved-value="0">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="City">
      <column name="City" 
              sql-type="varchar(150)" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="Country">
      <column name="Country" 
              sql-type="varchar(50)" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="Zipcode">
      <column name="Zipcode" 
              sql-type="varchar(50)" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="StreetNameNumber">
      <column name="StreetNameNumber" 
              sql-type="varchar(150)" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="WorldRegion">
      <column name="WorldRegion" 
              sql-type="varchar(100)" not-null="false" />
    </property>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The database model is:

```
WeatherForecasts : WeatherForecastID, LocationID
Locations:LocationID,City,Country,Zipcode, StreetNameNumber,WorldRegion.
```

When I run the program I get:

An association from the table WeatherForecasts refers to an unmapped class:

```
TravelAssistant.Model.HelperModels.Weather.LocationBase
```

Can someone point me where I got it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the fully qualified class name for the many-to-one association on the WeatherForecast mapping.

```
<many-to-one     
    name="ForecastLocation"
    cascade="all"
    class="TravelAssistant.Model.HelperModels.Location.LocationBase, TravelAssistant.Model"
    column="LocationID"
    not-null="false"   />
```